# Is Jazz-Flamenco a recognizable genre?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I'm trying to locate a genre that combines elements of jazz and flamenco. I recently [composed a piece](https://soundcloud.com/an_ant_sax/two-to-tango) that I think has that feel, and want to know what genre it might fit into.

Comment: Your question wasn't really on topic for us. I converted it to an "identify this genre" question, which we do cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flamenco Jazz exists and your piece seems to fit. One of the best known proponents of this style is guitarist Paco de Lucia. If you want to hear a good example you should listen to his 1980 live recording "Friday Night in San Francisco" together with John McLaughlin and Al Di Meola.
Here's a later live performance: